# Chrome thinks images aren't loades while they are?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw a few images on a canvas, to make sure the images are loaded when I draw them, I preload them using an array.

```
var num = 0,
    length = 3,
    images = {
        img1: '/img/img1.png',
        img2: '/img/img2.png',
        img3: '/img/img3.png'
    }


for(var i in images)
{
    var tmp = new Image();
    tmp.src = images[i];
    tmp.onload = function()
    {
        num ++;
        if(num == length)
        {
            startDoingStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

After preloading the startDoingStuff is fired where I use the image again

```
<snip>
this.img = new Image();
img.src = images[id].src;
</snip>
```

This works in Firefox and Opera but not in Chrome. Chrome probably thinks the images aren't loaded because if I put yet another onload it will work. Which is stupid because the images were already loaded :/

Only thing I found to solve this is by putting the loaded images in another array (or overwriting the original array) thus keeping reference.

Why doesn't Chrome not realize he already has the images in cache and use them when asked for?

Comment: How are you firing this script?

Comment: Like in the example, the place where I call the snip is in an object, which is in turn created in the startDoingStuff function

Comment: Image preloading involves other steps besides loading raw HTTP payload. Chrome may store the image content compressed in the cache and creating Image() from the scratch and setting src does not run the decoding step instantly. You are doing it wrong. Use the same Image() object for preloading and drawing on the <canvas> and then you are doing it correctly.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Doesn't the onload event only trigger when the image is actualy loaded, including the decoding step? That's what I would expect, anyway. Seeing how other browsers seem to agree with that, isn't this a case of Chrome being wrong? (Probably not, I'm sure I'm missing something but that's why I put it here, to learn)

Comment: Onload event only concerns the Image object in the question. If you create new Image object and set the same src it is not the same image per se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to preload the images are not very correct. Try next function:

```
function preloadImages(images,callback){
  var img,imgs,finished=0,onLoadError;

  if(images instanceof Array)imgs=images;
  else{
    imgs=[];
    for(var p in images)if(images.hasOwnProperty(p))imgs.push(images[p]);
  }

  onLoadError=function(ev){
    //ev=ev||window.event;
    // ev.type can be used to check 
    // when image is loaded succ (ev.type==="load")
    // or fail (ev.type==="error")
    finished++;
    if(finished===imgs.length)callback();
  };

  for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
    img=new Image();
    img.onload=img.onerror=onLoadError;
    img.src=imgs[i]; // NOTE: .src must be assigned after .onload and .onerror!
  }
}
```

You can use this function like in next examples:

```
preloadImages({ img1: '/img/img1.png',
                img2: '/img/img2.png',
                img3: '/img/img3.png'  },
              startDoingStuff);

// or

preloadImages([ '/img/img1.png',
                '/img/img2.png',
                '/img/img3.png'  ],
              startDoingStuff);
```